# A method that calls an array and returns a different array is giving a can't resolve B to a variable error

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compiler-errors

I am calling one array and returning another array that is sorted based on the other array.

I think my method is proper but when I try to print out from the new array in the main method i'm getting an error that reads, 
"`Cannot resolve B to a variable`."

B is the name of the new array that my method should return.
Thanks in advance.

```
package sort;

public class SortByFinal {

    public static int [][] sortByFinal(int n, int [][] A)
    {
        int [][]B = new int [n][3];

        int max = 0;

        for(int i =0; i<n; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i; j<n; j++)
            {
                max = Math.max(A[i][1], max);
            }

            for(int k = i; k<n; k++)
            {
                if(A[k][1] == max)
                {
                    B[k][0] = A[k][0];
                    B[k][1] = A[k][1];
                    B[k][2] = A[k][2];
                }
            }
        }

        return B;   

    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        int num = 5;

        int[][] now = new int [num][3];

        now[0][0] = 2342;

        now[0][1] = 88;

        now[0][2] = 98;

        now[1][0] = 3901;

        now[1][1] = 75;

        now[1][2] = 71;

        now[2][0] = 1444;

        now[2][1] = 60;

        now[2][2] = 85;

        now[3][0] = 5327;

        now[3][1] = 95;

        now[3][2] = 80;

        now[4][0] = 4888;

        now[4][1] = 83;

        now[4][2] = 100;

        //int [][] B = new int[num][3];

        sortByFinal(num, now);

        for(int i = 0; i<num; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<3; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(B[i][j]);//this gives me the "B cannot be resolved to a variable."
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }



    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`B` is defined in `sortByFinal()`, but not in `main()`.  To fix this, you could change your main to the follow:

```
int[][] B = sortByFinal(num, now);
```

Since `sortByFinal(num, now)` returns a `int[][]`, this will work.

In your code, you're calling the function, but not doing anything with the return value, and you do not have access to the local variables of other methods; hence, the message.